# Fourier series expansion of $x(t) = \sum\nolimits_{z \in \mathbb{Z}} (-1)^z \delta(t - 2z)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Find the Fourier series expansion of $x(t) = \sum\nolimits_{z \in \mathbb{Z}} (-1)^z \delta(t - 2z)$, where $\delta(\cdot)$ denotes the [Dirac delta function (unit impulse)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

I can infer that the period of $x(t)$ is $T = 4$.

However, I am stuck in finding the Fourier coefficients
$$
C_k = \frac1T \int\limits_{\tau_0}^{\tau_0 + T} x(\tau) e^{-i\frac{2 \pi k \tau}{T}} \operatorname d \tau
$$
where $\tau_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, $T = 4$ is the period, and $x(t)$ is defined as above. Can anyone give me some help as to how to handle that integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $x(t)$ given by

$$x(t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^k\delta(t-2k)$$

is periodic with period $4$.

We can write the Fourier Series for $x(t)$ as

$$x(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_ne^{i\pi nt/2}$$

where the Fourier coefficients $c_n$ are given by

$$\begin{align}
c_n&=\frac14\int_0^4 x(t)e^{-i\pi nt/2}dt\\\\
&\frac14 \int_0^4 \left(\delta(t)-\delta(t-2)\right)e^{-i\pi nt/2}dt\\\\
&=\frac14\left(1-e^{-i \pi n}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1-(-1)^n}{4}
\end{align}$$

Thus, we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{x(t)\sim \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1-(-1)^n}{4}e^{i\pi nt/2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos\left(\frac{(2n-1)\pi t}{2}\right)}$$

It is interesting to note that by formal term-by=term integration of the Fourier Series representation of $x(t)$, we have for $t\in [0,4)$

$$\int_0^t x(t')dt'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{(2n-1)\pi t}{2}\right)}{\frac{(2n-1)\pi }{2}}$$

which we recognize as the Fourier Series for the pulse function $p(t)$ given by

$$
p(t)=
\begin{cases}
1&,t\in [0,2)\\\\
\frac12&,t=2\\\\
0&,t\in(2,4)
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Ah! I was mistaken in regards to the period thanks to the $(-1)^k$ term. Can you please give some hints as to how the integral is evaluated?

Comment: Sure.  I'll add some detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, what you did was basically "pick out" the nonzero points of $x(t)$ over the interval $[0, 4)$, right?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  I used the "sifting property" of the Dirac Delta.  On $t\in [0,4)$, the "active" Dirac Deltas are $\delta (t)$, which sifts at $t=0$, and $\delta (t-2)$, which sifts at $t=2$.

Comment: Somehow the fun problems are solved by the good guys. I'd suspect that the final cosine series could be represented by a few delta functions in part because $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos(2n+1)x = \frac{\pi}{2} \left( \delta(x) - \delta(x-\pi)\right). $$ As always the remaining terms are left as an exercise of the reader.

Comment: @Leucippus You and I seem to enjoy the same types of problems.  It is an interesting check to see if one can recover a function at $0$, $2$, etc.  by integrating the FS representation over an interval that covers the point of interest only.